# Performance impact of checking flags while looping through pandas dataframe columns

Tags: python, pandas, performance

I work on a program that make different kind of calculation on dataset columns.

Currently there are 3 types of calculation that are made by 3 separate functions, depending on a flag defined at runtime for each.

```
import pandas as pd

dataframe = pd.read_csv("my_dataset.csv")
for column in dataframe.columns:
    if flag_operation_1:
        do_operation_1(dataframe[column])
    if flag_operation_2:
        do_operation_2(dataframe[column])
    if flag_operation_3:
        do_operation_3(dataframe[column])
```

It works well, however I know that some dataset can be very large and I wonder what is the speed impact to check for each flag for each columns (knowing that the flags remain the same for the entire dataset, it looks like it's a loss of time).

Is it negligible ? If not, is there a way I could both check flags once for all and loop only once through each column ?

Comment: What is `flag_operation_X`? A constant defined at runtime? This test should not be significant if your `do_operation_X` are CPU or IO bounded.

Comment: Also, what is the output of `do_operation_X`? are you storing a value in a new column of the dataframe?

Comment: you can check this yourself using `line_profiler` and some large testing dataframe

Answer (score 0):

If you felt that the testing of the flags could be a performance problem you might think about creating a list of methods that pass the flag tests and calling only those.

perhaps something like:

```py
import pandas

flags = [True, True, False]
methods = [
    lambda column: print("Hello"),
    lambda column: print(column),
    lambda column: print("World"),
]
tasks = [method for flag, method in zip(flags, methods) if flag]

dataframe = pandas.read_csv("my_dataset.csv")
for column in dataframe.columns:
    for task in tasks:
        task(column)
```